# Nhibernate Truncates stored procedure input parameters when parameter values are more than 4000 characters

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I specify the length of string input parameters of a stored procedure in Nhibernate mapping files.

this is my mapping contents

```
<sql-query name="Sp_News" resultset-ref="NewsPackResultSet" cacheable="false">

    <query-param name="SearchString"       type="System.String" />
    <query-param name="StartDate"          type="System.DateTime" />

          exec dbo.Sp_News:SearchString,:StartDate

</sql-query>
```

When the length of SearchString parameter is more than 4000 characters, the Nhibernate Truncates that parameter values. How can i solve this limitation?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that's something you should validate before even calling the stored proc. Why would a search parameter be more than a few characters or words anyway?

Comment: This still sounds like something you should validate up front. If you're sending data to the stored proc, you shouldn't send something that 'might' fail simply because it was too long. If you're storing an article why do you want to constrain it to 4000 characters?

Comment: hi, is your problem solved? I have same one :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this question and also found the answer:

```
IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("Sp_News");
query.SetParameter("SearchString", longString, NHibernateUtil.StringClob);
```

**NHibernateUtil.StringClob** is the key :-)